# The image size is been increased when saving

Tags: vb.net, image, image-processing

When I save a image from a picturebox using `Picturebox1.Image.Save`, the saved image size is much larger than the original image size (for example, from 1.5 MB to 15 MB). What can I do for the image will be saved in the same size of the original image?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably load a `JPEG` or `PNG` image into the Picturebox, which are compressed file formats. However Picturebox1.Image.Save saves it as a bitmap, if you do not specify the type. Bitmaps are uncompressed and therefore quite large. You can change this by using

```
Picturebox1.Image.Save(Outputfilename, Drawing.Imaging.Imageformats.Png)
```

This saves the image in the PNG-Format, which is much smaller.

Comment: Thank you! Just a one comment - jpeg format works for me better.